# adding __getitem__ accessor to Python class method

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing

I'm attempting to add an item getter (`__getitem__`, to provide the `[]` syntax) to a class method so that I can use some unique-ish syntax to provide types to functions outside the normal parentheses, like the following. The syntax on the last line (of this first snippet) is really the goal for this whole endeavor.

```py
class MyClass:

    @typedmethod
    def compute_typed_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self, args, kwargs)
        result = TypedMethod.requested_type(kwargs)(value)
        self.my_other_method()
        return result

    def my_other_method(self):
        print('Doing some other things!')
        return 3


a = MyClass()
a.compute_typed_value[int]('12345') # returns int value 12345
```

Additionally, I'd like to retain the intuitive behavior that a defined function can be called like a function, potentially with a default value for the type, like so:

```py
a = MyClass()
a.compute_typed_value('12345') 
# should return whatever the default type is, with the value of '12345', 
# or allow some other default behavior
```

In a broader context, this would be implemented as a piece of an API adapter that implements a generic request processor, and I'd like the data to come out of the API adapter in a specific format. So the way that this might look in actual use could be something like the following:

```py
@dataclass
class MyAPIData:
    property_a: int = 0
    property_b: int = 0

class MyAPIAdapter:
    _session
    def __init__(self, token):
        self._init_session(token)

    @typedmethod
    def request_json(self, url, **kwargs):
        datatype = TypedMethod.requested_type(kwargs)
        response_data = self._session.get(url).json()
        if datatype:
            response_data = datatype(**response_data)
        return response_data

    def fetch_myapidata(self, search):
        return self.request_json[MyAPIData](f"/myapi?q={search}")
```

I'm attempting to achieve this kind of behavior with a decorator that I can throw onto any function that I want to enable this behavior. Here is my current full implementation:

```py
from functools import partial

class TypedMethod:

    _REQUESTED_TYPE_ATTR = '__requested_type'

    def __init__(self, method):
        self._method = method
        print(method)
        self.__call__ = method.__call__

    def __getitem__(self, specified_type, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'getting typed value: {specified_type}')
        if not isinstance(specified_type, type):
            raise TypeError("Only Type Accessors are supported - must be an instance of `type`")
            
        return partial(self.__call__, **{self.__class__._REQUESTED_TYPE_ATTR: specified_type})
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        return self._method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    
    @classmethod
    def requested_type(cls, foo_kwargs):
        return foo_kwargs[cls._REQUESTED_TYPE_ATTR] if cls._REQUESTED_TYPE_ATTR in foo_kwargs else None

def typedmethod(foo):
    print(f'wrapping {foo.__name__} with a Typed Method: {foo}')
    _typed_method = TypedMethod(foo)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('WRAPPER', self, args, kwargs)
        return _typed_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    _typed_method.__call__ = wrapper
    return _typed_method

class MyClass:

    @typedmethod
    def compute_typed_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self, args, kwargs)
        result = TypedMethod.requested_type(kwargs)(value)
        print(result)
        self.my_other_method()
        return result

    def my_other_method(self):
        print('Doing some other things!')
        return 3


a = MyClass()
a.compute_typed_value[int]('12345')
```

If you run this code, it will fail stating that 'TypedMethod' object has no attribute 'my_other_method'. Further inspection reveals that the first line of `compute_typed_value` is not printing what one would intuitively expect from the code:

> `<__main__.TypedMethod object at 0x10754e790> () {'__requested_type': <class 'int'>}`

Specifically, the first item printed, which is a `TypedMethod` instead of a `MyClass` instance

Basically, the idea is use the `__getitem__` callout to generate a `functools.partial` so that the subsequent call to the resulting function contains the `__getitem__` key in a known "magic" `kwargs` value, which should hypothetically work, except that now the `self` reference that is available to `MyClass.compute_typed_value` is actually a reference to the `TypedMethod` instance generated by the wrapper instead of the expected `MyClass` instance. I've attempted a number of things to get the `MyClass` instance passed as `self`, but since it's implemented as a decorator, the instance isn't available at the time of decoration, meaning that somehow it needs to be a bound method at the time of function execution, I think.

---

I know I could just pass this value in as like the first positional argument, but I *want* it to work with the square bracket annotation because I think it'd be cool and more readable. This is mostly a learning exercise to understand more of Python's inner workings, so the answer could ultimately be "no".

Comment: Would using 'MyClass().my_other_method()' instead of 'self.my_other_method()' inside of 'compute_typed_value' be what you're looking for? It does get the job done.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, because `self.my_other_method()` may potentially refer to parameters only accessible through `self`. The problem here is that in my proposed solution, `self` very unintuitively references the `TypedMethod` instance that wraps the function, rather than the otherwise standard instance of the class that defines the function.

Comment: You are misusing terminology here. There is not a single annotation in your entire code. The term "annotation" is synonymous in Python with "type hint". Likewise, the tag `python-typing` refers to the tools available to create and validate type hints/annotations. This does not take away from your problem per se. I find it interesting, but I suggest you edit your question because your terminology and tags are confusing.

Comment: If I understood your goal correctly, you are interested in a way to modify functions (via decorator perhaps) in a way that adds a `__getitem__` method to them, which takes a `type` instance and causes the subsequent call to... do what exactly? Attempt to coerce the result to the specified type? It would help, if you provided a few more examples of **using** this construct along with your desired **output** for those calls.

Comment: I updated the question to add some more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never thought I would use a Python class this way, but if the pattern fits...

I put a cleaned-up example of the below answer in [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/AndroxxTraxxon/e9b0ca46108fc17cdc1996d34a724d38) that shows the same implementation and usage.

---

The issue I was having was that the class instance reference (`self`) was being overridden due to the reassignment of the function itself via a decorator. My solution is basically to add another class-level decorator to manually put that reference back. This looks a little different than my originally asked question due to a change in naming, but the essence is still the same. We define a class that is itself used as the decorator. Python just allows this because class types, when called, are function calls themselves, to create and init a new instance of the class. This also allows us to provide a few more magic methods to make other quality of life items easier. Here's what that looks like:

```py
from functools import partial, wraps
from types import MethodType

from functools import partial, wraps
from types import MethodType, FunctionType
from typing import Any, Callable

class subscriptable:
    _SUBSCRIPT_KEY = '___SUBSCRIPT_KEY'
    _HAS_SUBSCRIPTABLE_METHODS = '___HAS_SUBSCRIPTABLE_METHODS'

    _callout: Callable
    def __init__(self, callout: Callable, instance: Any = None):
        if instance is not None and isinstance(callout, FunctionType):
            self._callout = MethodType(callout, instance)
        else:
            self._callout = callout

    def bind(self, instance):
        return self.__class__(self._callout, instance=instance)

    def __getitem__(self, specified_type):
        return partial(self.__call__, **{self.__class__._SUBSCRIPT_KEY: specified_type})
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """A transparent passthrough to the wrapped method"""
        return self._callout(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} {self._callout}>"
    
    @classmethod
    def has_key(cls, foo_kwargs):
        """A utility method to determine whether the provided kwargs has the expected subscript key"""
        return cls._SUBSCRIPT_KEY in foo_kwargs
    
    @classmethod
    def key(cls, foo_kwargs:dict):
        """A utility method that allows the subscript key to be consumed by the wrapped method, without needing to know the inner workings"""
        return foo_kwargs.pop(cls._SUBSCRIPT_KEY, None)
    
    @classmethod
    def container(cls, clazz):
        """A decorator for classes containing `subscriptable` methods"""
        if not hasattr(clazz, cls._HAS_SUBSCRIPTABLE_METHODS):
            orig_init = clazz.__init__
            @wraps(clazz.__init__)
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                for attr_name in dir(self):
                    attr_value = getattr(self, attr_name)
                    if isinstance(attr_value, cls):
                        setattr(self, attr_name, attr_value.bind(self))
                orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            clazz.__init__ = __init__
            setattr(clazz, cls._HAS_SUBSCRIPTABLE_METHODS, True)
        return clazz
```

---

As a bonus feature, As some previously written answers allude to, class functions are not the only place that something like this might be useful, so this also allows for standalone functions to exhibit the same behavior. See this example, and its output:

```py
@subscriptable
def other_typed_value(value, **kwargs):
    subscript = subscriptable.key(kwargs)
    print(subscript, value)

value = other_typed_value[int]('12345')
value = other_typed_value('12345')
print("Standard function str:", other_typed_value)
```

Produces the output:

```
<class 'int'> 12345
None 12345
Standard function str: <subscriptable <function other_typed_value at 0x000001DC809384C0>>
```

---

And finally, the original point of the question, whether we can apply this pattern to class methods. The answer is yes, but with the assistance of yet another decorator. This is where `subscriptable.container` steps in. Since we can't access the instance at the time of class definition, I used an additional decorator to provide a pre-init hook that initializes all the functions so they are usable as expected (as properly bound class methods, even!), available even in the `__init__` function. This kind of processing is probably pretty slow, but for my use case, it's mostly for singletons anyway.

```
@subscriptable.container
class MyClass:

    @subscriptable
    def compute_typed_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self, args, kwargs)
        if subscriptable.has_key(kwargs):
            value = subscriptable.key(kwargs)(value)
        self.my_other_method()
        return value

    def my_other_method(self):
        print('Doing some other things!')
        return 3


a = MyClass()
value = a.compute_typed_value[int]('12345')
print(value, type(value))
value = a.compute_typed_value('12345')
print(value, type(value))
print("Class Method str:", a.compute_typed_value)
```

Anyhoo, the above code yields the following output, which you'll notice has all the correct references in the places they were missing before. great success!

```
Doing some other things!
12345 <class 'int'>
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000001DC808EB1C0> () {}
Doing some other things!
12345 <class 'str'>
Class Method str: <subscriptable <bound method MyClass.compute_typed_value of <__main__.MyClass object at 0x000001DC808EB1C0>>>
```

I was hoping to do this without a second decorator, but a single class decorator to enable the desired behavior when I'm already using one is a price I'm willing to pay.

Comment: This breaks if you ever try to create more than one instance of a class, since it tries to bind the methods once per instance. Look what happens if you [throw in a `b = MyClass()`](https://ideone.com/dX8iKp) in your example.

Comment: Binding on lookup with `__get__`, as Blckknght's answer suggests, removes this issue.

Comment: oh, damn. you're totally right. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: well, not quite a blank drawing board. switching up the way the `subscriptable.container` method did the binding, as well as the bind method itself, we're able to overcome that issue as well. Don't get me wrong, this is cursed code, but the entire premise kind of was from the beginning. I've updated my answer to address that

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing some odd stuff with `__call__` that doesn't quite work. Fixing those issues will likely make `self` refer to what you expect in `compute_typed_value`.

The main problems:

- Assigning a new function to the `__call__` attribute of an instance doesn't work to change the object's behavior when it's actually called. You attempt this twice, but the `TypedMethod` object's hard-coded `__call__` method is getting called instead of any of the other things you try (you first set `_method.__call__` and separately `wrapper` to be called, neither of which make much sense to me).
- Your `typed_method` decorator returns the `TypedMethod` object it creates, rather than the wrapper function. Because `TypedMethod` is not a descriptor, there's no binding logic for `MyClass.compute_typed_value`, so there's no good way for the instance of `MyClass` to get passed in anywhere. Normally this works because functions are descriptors, returning bound method objects. However, it's going to be a bit complicated to make that work here, since you want a `__getattr__` to work on the bound object.

So, I think you should change things up to use two different classes.

The first is a descriptor class, that when looked up, has binding behavior so that you can get the `self` value to pass in to the method. When bound, it returns an instance of the second class.

The second class handles the indexing by type. It has a `__getitem__` method, which returns a `partial` that passes both the `self` value that the first class captured, and the type that it has been indexed with (as a secret keyword argument).

Here's what that looks like:

```
class typedmethod:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None: return self # class lookup
        return TypeIndexer(instance, self.method)

class TypeIndexer:
    def __init__(self, instance, method):
        self.instance = instance
        self.method = method

    def __getitem__(self, type):
        return partial(method, self.instance, _secret_kwarg=type)
```

I've left out the logic to hide the name `_secret_kwarg` in a class variable somewhere, and to have a public API for getting it out of a `kwargs` dict. It would actually be a whole lot easier if you just passed the type in to the method as a public argument. Maybe make it the first positional argument after `self`, or a kwarg with a meaningful name? The fact that the user doesn't actually supply it directly wouldn't be much more confusing than `TypedMethod.requested_type(kwargs)(value)` is now.

Of course, if we follow that logic to its conclusion, you could rewrite the whole `obj.method[type](args)` pattern to be `obj.method(type, args)` and it would be a whole lot easier.

Comment: 2 things: the motive for utilizing any reference to `__call__` was simply that it didn't work with simpler methods like the ones you suggested. 

Passing in a type as a positional argument is what I have been doing, and I figured that's where this would lead. I was just playing around with the language to see if this arbitrary syntax was possible, to mirror what has been done with the class type hinting syntax.

Comment: Except that [I found a reasonable workaround!!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808600/4802259) As long as you're willing to tolerate another decorator applied at the class level, this thing works great!

Answer (score 2):

We can make `SomeInstance` class with a `getter` that `return`s `MyClass`'s instance by invoking the descriptor and setting it as a class attribute when `init`'ing `MyClass`. Here `MyClass._instance` *is* the instance of `MyClass` (it's `MyClass`'s `self`), which we can pass to the instance method `my_other_method` within the decorated `computed_typed_value` method:

```
class SomeInstance:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            print('instance is None')
            return self
        print(f'getting instance of {owner.__name__} via {self.__class__.__name__}')
        return instance

class MyClass:
    _instance = SomeInstance()
    def __init__(self):
        MyClass._instance = self._instance
        print(f'MyClass._instance type is {type(MyClass._instance)}')

    def my_other_method(self):
        print('Doing some other things!')
        return 3

    @typedmethod
    def compute_typed_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self, args, kwargs)
        result = TypedMethod.requested_type(kwargs)(value)
        print(result)
        x = MyClass._instance.my_other_method()
        print(x)
        return result

a = MyClass()
a.compute_typed_value[int]('12345')
```

Outputs:

```
wrapping compute_typed_value with a Typed Method: <function MyClass.compute_typed_value at 0x7f5dce1ed790>
<function MyClass.compute_typed_value at 0x7f5dce1ed790>
getting instance of MyClass via SomeInstance
MyClass._instance type is <class '__main__.MyClass'>
getting typed value: <class 'int'>
WRAPPER 12345 () {'__requested_type': <class 'int'>}
('12345',) {'__requested_type': <class 'int'>}
<__main__.TypedMethod object at 0x7f5deed5a7c0> () {'__requested_type': <class 'int'>}
12345
Doing some other things!
3
12345
```

Comment: This uses a second instance of `MyClass`, which is fundamentally the same issue with my initial solution. The issue is that the reference to `self` is broken, and not so much that I couldn't identify which function to call.

Comment: Gotcha! I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing how `typedmethod` is being defined in your answer now, so I'm not sure how this would be replicated. I'm also not understanding what this instance management is doing with your `SomeInstance` class, passing around instances of methods, rather than the instances of the classes those methods are defined in.

Comment: @David Culbreth okay last try, I think this is what you're looking for! I did have to include an init for MyClass, so hopefully that doesn't conflict with whatever you're intending to do with it.

Comment: I see this does work with my initially proposed versions of `typedmethod` and `TypedMethod`, but to me the pattern isn't great, because the `self` definition in the function defined by `MyClass` still references a value that is not what one would intuitively assume upon the first read. [I came up with a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808600/4802259) that restores this default behavior with a second decorator, and doesn't require juggling instances inside the class or function definition.

Comment: Nice! I would argue that is wayyy less intuitive than my answer, at least in my opinion. But you're answering your own question so I guess you know best lol. Also, I named it 'MyClass._instance' which isn't "intuitive" as 'self'... but it's pretty intuitive, and my answer is pretty short (few lines of code).

Comment: My main issue with your answer (and inherently the code in my initial question) is that `self` still isn't the expected instance of the `MyClass` object -- it's replaced with the TypedMethod, which means it'd be really easy to get tripped up when reading through a class definition, where one would naturally assume that a `self` reference indeed refers to the instance of the class whose function was initially called to begin with

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Applying your concept to a class has a giant roadblock. This is what the decorator does:

```
    def typewrap(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            #...do type checking

            #call decorated method
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            
        #there is no `self` of `func` to store
        #and scope is changing
        #`self` of `func` is abandoned here
        return TypedMethod(wrapper)
```

You need a reference to `self` of `func` that you can pass to `TypedMethod`, before wrapper is run, but it doesn't exist yet. It also won't exist, because `wrapper` will be called from the `TypedMethod` instance, instead of your class instance.

---

If you get rid of the class scope, your idea becomes very simple to implement. A bunch of your original logic is not necessary (mainly `__call__`). Here is an example:

```
from functools import partial

class TypedMethod:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self._cb = callback

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not isinstance(key, type):
            raise TypeError("key must be an instance of `type`")
            
        return partial(self._cb, key)
       
       
def typedmethod(func):
    def wrapper(argtype:type, *args, **kwargs):
        #test all arguments
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg, argtype):
                raise TypeError(f"all arguments must be of type: {argtype.__name__}")
        for _,v in kwargs.items():
            if not isinstance(v, argtype):
                raise TypeError(f"all arguments must be of type: {argtype.__name__}")
                
        #call wrapped method
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        
    #assign wrapper as the callback
    return TypedMethod(wrapper)
```

```
def dofunc(a):
    print(a)
    
@typedmethod
def dotype(x,y,z,a):
    print(x,y,z)
    dofunc(a)

dotype[int](22, 35, 2, a=12345)
#22, 35, 2
#12345
```

Comment: I'm aware that removing the class scope does simplify the problem, but I had been using classes to help organize the code, and facilitate things like managing authentication tokens for an API.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth ~ It doesn't change the fact that you can't get a reference to the proper `self`. You can want this to work with classes with all of your might, and it just wont. The second you hand everything off to `TypedMethod` the most essential piece of data you need is lost, and there is no way to go around `TypedMethod` because you need it to run `__getitem__` before you can do anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared, and the same conclusion that I came to.

Comment: Except that I couldn't stop thinking about this yesterday, and I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808600/4802259) that utilizes a second (class-level) decorator to provide a pre-init hook to bind the methods